# Property [costo] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

i need to print the price of a service, but can't find the column with the price.
maybe I'm doing something wrong with relationships, but I can't figure it out on my own

**database:**
[image]

Controller:

```
  public function details(Request $request,$id){

    $datax = [
      'category_name' => 'apps',
      'page_name' => 'calendar',
      'has_scrollspy' => 0,
      'scrollspy_offset' => '',

  ];



  
    $evento = Eventos::find($id);
    $servicio = \App\Models\Eventos::select("servicio_id")->where('servicio_id', $evento->id)->get('servicio_id');
    $event = Eventos::find($id);
    $event->asistencia = $request->asistencia;
    $event->cancelado = $request->cancelado;
    $event->save();

    return view("evento",[
      "event" => $event,
      "servicio" => $servicio
    ])->with($datax);

  }
```

**blade.php**

```
  <div class="input-group mb-4">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">$</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="{{$servicio->costo}}" class="form-control col-md-3" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to print the "costo" column  in relation to service_id

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use laravel elequent relationship one to one.
if you have this two `Servicio.php` & `Evento.php` in `App/Models` or whatever your models name is, only replace your models in below code do this:

**1-**
in `App/Models/Servicio.php` define this relationship:

```
 public function evento()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Evento::class);
    }
```

in `App/Models/Evento.php` define this relationship:

```
 public function servicio()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Servicio::class);
    }
```

now in controller add this:

```
$evento = Eventos::where('id' , $id)->with('servicio')->first();
```

in blade use this:

```
  <input type="text" value="{{$evento->servicio->costo}}" >
```

**2-** also you can do this but i suggest you the first one:
only in your Codes change this:
$servicio = \App\Models\Servicio::where('id', $evento->servicio_id)->first();